# Facebook SDK checking if user is already fan

Tags: facebook, api, sdk

Hello I would like to check if user is already fan of my fanpage. I already found ready script to do that but it have so much parsing errors. Could you help me and fix that code?

```
<!--?php require('facebook.php');
$config = array(
     'appId' =?--> 'your facebook app id',
     'secret' => 'your facebook app secret code',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if (isset($user_id)) {
    try {          
        $likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes/your_facebook_page_id_here', 'GET');            
        if (!empty($likes['data'])) // if user has liked the page then $likes['data'] wont be empty otherwise it will be empty
        {
            echo 'Thank you for liking our fan page!';         
            // you can write some custom code here to award users some points or some badge        
        }
       else {
            echo 'You have not liked our fan page! Like it now:';
            ?>                  
            <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Farkhitech&width&height=290&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&header=true&stream=false&show_border=true&appId=1392604484339363" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:290px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe> //replace this with your own Facebook like box code
            <!--?php }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $login_url = $facebook-?-->getLoginUrl();
        echo '<a href="' . $login_url . '">Please click here to login into your Facebook account.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo '<a href="' . $login_url . '">Please lick here to login into your Facebook account</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Like gating is not allowed

Comment: I want to give little gift for everyone who liked my fanpage

Comment: Incentivizing likes are also not allowed

Answer (score 1):

You would need to authorize the user with the `user_likes` permissions and then use the following API call:

```
/me/likes/[page-id]
```

As you can see, that´s the API call in your example code. Without telling us EXACTLY what errors you get, it´s impossible to help. But it does not matter anyway, because:

- Incentivizing likes is not allowed, you can´t reward users in any way for liking your Page according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).
- You would need to get `user_likes` approved by Facebook, else it will only work for users with a role in the App. Facebook will definitely not approve it for something that is not allowed.

**In other words: Not possible and not allowed.**